# Reactfire, aren't mixins deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, reactfire

I am browsing the reactfire github and they use mixins.

I thought they were deprecated? Am I behind the times?

Comment: I don't think they are deprecated, they just aren't supported with ES6/ES2015 classes. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins

Comment: Yes, don't use react-fire. just bind a listener to a firebase ref and update state when the data changes.

Comment: Would I do something like this: `componentWillMount() { firebaseRef.then(response => this.setState({ data: response })); }` ?

Answer (score 8):

You might want to take a look to this brief answer: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-Firebase-with-ES6-on-React

> The problem with ReactFire is because it uses Mixins, it's not compatible with ES6 classes. After chatting with Jacob Turner, we wanted to create a way to allow the one way binding of ReactFire with ES6 classes along some more features like two way data binding and listening to Firebase endpoints without actually binding a state property to them. Thus, re-base was built.

So, here's *a Relay inspired library for building React.js + Firebase applications*: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base

This was helpful to me, I hope it'll be the same with you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from **re-base**, also have a look at **react-redux-firebase** as mentioned [in this **reactfire** discussion](https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/issues/38):

#### react-redux-firebase

*Redux bindings for Firebase. Includes Higher Order Component for use with React.*

- http://react-redux-firebase.com
- https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase